# Rao Blackwell theorem for unbiased estimator of Poisson

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Use the Rao-Blackwell Theorem to find a better estimator of $e^{-\lambda}$ than $T = \frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n I(X_j = 0)$

I calculated the estimator from teh rao-blackwell theorem as follows

\begin{align}
E[T|e^{-\lambda}] &= E\left[\left.\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n I(X_j = 0)\right\vert e^{-\lambda}\right]\\
&= \frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n E[I(X_j = 0)|e^{-\lambda}]
\end{align}

However, since $e^{-\lambda}$ is just a constant, i get $E[T|e^{-\lambda}] = e^{-\lambda}$? doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [1], you should improve the estimator $T$ using a sufficient statistic. The natural one for a sample of i.i.d. Poisson variables is the sum
$S=S(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, see [2].
The conditional distribution of $X_i$ given $S$ is Binomial$(S,1/n)$,
so $$P(X_i=0|S)=(1-1/n)^S \,, \tag{1} $$
whence the Rao-Blackwell estimator is
$$E[T|S]= (1-1/n)^S \,.$$

**Addendum:** $T$ itself is an estimator for $e^{-\lambda}$, as its mean (given the true parameter is $\lambda$) is exactly $e^{-\lambda}$. The conditional expectation $E(T|S)$ still has the same mean (by the tower property of conditional expectation), but has lower variance, so is more accurate. Crucially, $E(T|S)$ is   computable from the sample, unlike $E_\lambda(T)$ itself.

**Addendum 2:** As the OP requested in a comment,  let's verify $(1)$ directly.
Since the sum of $n$ i.i.d. Poisson$(\lambda)$ variables has Poisson$(n\lambda)$ distribution, for integer $s \ge 0$ we have
$$ P(S=s)=e^{-n\lambda}\frac{(n\lambda)^s}{s!} \,. \tag{2}$$
Similarly, the sum of $n-1\, $ i.i.d. Poisson$(\lambda)$ variables has Poisson$((n-1)\lambda)$ distribution, so
$$ P(X_i=0, S=s)=P(X_1=0) \cdot P(\sum_{j \ne i} X_j= s) $$ $$=
e^{-\lambda} \cdot e^{-(n-1)\lambda}\frac{((n-1)\lambda)^s}{s!} \,. \tag{3}$$

Dividing $(3)$ by $(2)$ gives

$$P(X_i=0|S=s)=(1-1/n)^s \,, \tag{4} $$
as claimed.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Poisson_distribution

Comment: I don't see where you used the fact that we are trying to find an estimator for $e^{-\lambda}$ rather than $\lambda$

Comment: We used it in the property of the original statistic $T$, namely, that when the true parameter is $\lambda$, we have $E_\lambda(T)=e^{-\lambda}$.  Did you read the wiki article  on Rao-Blackwell?

Comment: Ps I never met Rao, but Blackwell was super friendly when I arrived in Berkeley in 1993

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure how you deduced $P(X_i = 0|S) = (1 - 1/n)^S$. Shouldn't it be $\frac{\binom{n-1}{S}}{\binom{n}{s}}? Also shouldn't your value for $E[T|S]$ be $n$ times $P(X_i = 0|S)$ by linearity of expectation?

Comment: @Math_Day  I added an explanation. Note that in the definition of $T$ there is a factor $1/n$.